# Can't install ioncube load with php-fpm

Tags: php, ioncube

PHP5-FPM won't start, when ioncube-loader extension will be enabled.

What i've done:

**Prerequisites:**

OS:

```
> uname -a
Linux halali 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PHP:

```
> php -v
PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:13:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

**Steps taken to enable the extension:**

```
wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
tar xfv ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar
```

Since there is php 5.6 installed in my VM, i copied the 5.6-version of ioncube loader into the extension directory /usr/lib/php5/20131226.

```
> php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20131226 => /usr/lib/php5/20131226

> ls -l /usr/lib/php5/20131226/
total 4200
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89240 Oct  4 16:23 curl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  114200 Oct  4 16:23 gd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23656 Oct 25  2014 geoip.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  384200 Oct 21  2014 imagick.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  415168 Oct  4 16:23 intl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1418736 Nov 28 15:59 ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39696 Aug  1  2014 json.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48072 Oct  4 16:23 mcrypt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  107880 Oct 25  2014 memcached.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  103720 Oct 25  2014 memcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  155560 Oct  4 16:23 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   60504 Oct  4 16:23 mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  160344 Oct  4 16:23 opcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32072 Oct  4 16:23 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  122440 Oct  4 16:23 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31576 Oct  4 16:23 readline.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  865166 Aug 25  2014 xdebug.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   98728 Nov 28 15:27 xhprof.so
```

In /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, i added following line:

```
extension=ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
```

But then, php5-fpm isnt able to start:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
[....] Restarting php5-fpm (via systemctl): php5-fpm.serviceJob for php5-fpm.service failed. See 'systemctl status php5-fpm.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

I've also tried to addres the full path and filename of the .so-File in php-ini. It won't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini you have to write:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
```

instead of

```
extension=...
```

The difference is, that the ioncube loader is a core extension like xdebug sitting directly into the zend engine itself.